# I'm not sure why my shape is not moving

Tags: java, game-mechanics, swing

So I am trying to teach my self how to my develop games with java by cloning older games. At the moment I am cloning Pong, and I can not figure out why my paddle is not moving. The move method should be updating the player paddle's position every frame, but is not. If someone can help me that would be great. Also any tips on code that I am using, that I shouldn't be would be appreciated as well! (I am somewhat new to this website as well, so please don't criticize me if I am using the wrong format or what not. I am just looking for help from a community that understands what they are doing more than I.)

Pong Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Pong extends JFrame{

    public Pong(String title){
        super(title);

        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new GamePanel(this, 35), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Pong("Pong!");
    }

}
```

GamePanel Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    private static final int WIDTH = 1200;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 675;
    private static final Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    private int targetFPS;
    private double period;
    private int currentFPS;

    public GamePanel(Pong pong, int fps){
        this.pong = pong;
        targetFPS = fps;
        period = 1000 / (double)targetFPS;

        setPreferredSize(SIZE);
        setMinimumSize(SIZE);
        setMaximumSize(SIZE);
    }

    public void addNotify(){
        start();
    }
    public void start(){
        if (animator == null || !running){
            animator = new Thread(this, "Animator");
            animator.start();
        }
    }
    public void stop(){
        running = false;
    }


    private Pong pong;
    private boolean running;
    private Thread animator;

    private double deltaTime = 0;
    public double getDeltaTime() { return deltaTime; }

    public void run() {

        long beforeTime = 0;
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double totalTime = 0;

        initialize();
        running = true;
        while(running){
            beforeTime = currentTime;
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            deltaTime = currentTime - beforeTime;
            totalTime += deltaTime;

            if (totalTime >= period){
                update();
                repaint();

                totalTime = 0;
            }
        }

        System.exit(0);

    }



    private Paddle player;
    private Paddle enemy;

    public void initialize(){
        player = new Paddle(1100, 100); 
        enemy = new Paddle(100, 100);
    }


    public void update(){
        player.move(10);

        for (Paddle paddle : Paddle.paddles){
            paddle.update();
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0,  0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        for (Paddle paddle : Paddle.paddles){
            paddle.render(g2d);
        }

    }
}
```

And Finally, The Paddle Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Paddle{

    public static ArrayList<Paddle> paddles = new ArrayList<Paddle>();

    private static final int width = 12;
    private static final int height = 120;
    private static final int velocity = 5;

    private Rectangle shape;
    private int xLocation;
    private int yLocation;

    public Paddle(int x, int y){

        xLocation = x;
        yLocation = y;

        shape = new Rectangle(xLocation, yLocation, width, height);

        paddles.add(this);
    }

    public void move(int i){
        yLocation += i;
    }

    public void update(){
        shape = new Rectangle(xLocation, yLocation, width, height);
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g2d){
        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.draw(shape);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should use [paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) instead of [paint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) (paint method is used by Swing it self. Avoid it in application code.)
So first of all refactor the method of Pong this way:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
   super.paintComponent(g);   
   ....
}
```

Moreover, the way you are trying to use thread is not correct and safe, at least for a Swing application. When you need to execute operations into a separate thread that interacts with the state of a Swing application you should use [invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

So you should refactor your update method using timer:

```
int delay = 33; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      //here update the status of your game   

      //refresh
      repaint(); 

  }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

This should be enough. I don't see any other error. I suggest you to read some tutorials on how works painting in Swing, for example [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).